# How to stream video from my server to client browser using DirectShow?

Tags: asp.net, video, web, video-streaming, directshow

I'm developing an `ASP.NET` application that's required to stream on-demand videos from server to client. Now I consider using `DirectShow` to do some kind of processing works before the video is transmitted over Internet. Following this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80413/Streaming-Server-using-Direct-Show-and-Windows-Med), I know I can transfer video stream over network through `WMAsfWriter` after it's processed by `DirectShow` and the output is a URL that the client can get access to through `Windows Media player`. But in my `ASP.NET` application, I want the video stream played on the web page of the client browser such as `Chrome`. I'm not sure if the output URL can be parsed by client browser and the video stream can be played there directly, so I want to ask that is it possible? If not, what extra steps do I need to take to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can made WebRTC streamer DirectShow filter and open this stream in browser. Ways like WMP / VLC player require ActiveX, that, really, dead technology now. Even Microsoft Edge do not support it anymore. WebRTC most common way today. Web version of Skype and a lot of other apps use it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply as I'm very busy recently. Could you elaborate a little bit about how to connect `DirectShow` with `WebRTC`? Does`WebRTC` get the video stream from the `DirectShow` filter directly or it just get it from the URL generated by the `WASFWriter` I mentioned in my question?